# Singleton design pattern in a Cluster environment

Tags: java, design-patterns

Singleton object will create instances per jvm basis. How it works in clustering environment?

What are the alternatives?

Comment: It would be useful to know what you are using to create your cluster.

Comment: I used Apache Http webserver,Apache Tomcat server and mod_jk.dll

Comment: I think the question is legitimate after the information about technologies used.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194129/singleton-in-cluster-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to not create a Singleton:

http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/

Google thinks they're a bad idea.

Clustered caching sounds like what you want.  Maybe a Terracotta or a Coherence is a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can use Terracotta to cluster the JVM. I think it will guarantee the singleton instance.

But I think it's not what you want. Singletons are just "global state". So you don't need the same instance as long as the state (field values) in it is the same. I don't know how you cluster your application, but I guess you can have cluster-wide data.