# Spring bean how to access server resource only once?

Tags: spring, ioc-container

I have a Spring bean which refers connection factory to access J2C resource. This code is deployed in webSphere server in 2 jvms load balanced. I had the readAuth method as init-method in bean xml but it was called multiple times during a load test. Since Spring singleton is per bean per container, I assumed there are multiple containers causing it to load multiple times. So I removed the init-method and changed the username and password to static and added null check in get methods. But now also, readAuth method is being called multiple times. I want to ensure this method is called only once per jvm since this method access server resource and connection is timing out during load test.
Please suggest a best approach on how to write this class. Thanks in advance.

```
    <bean id="J2CUtils"
        class="test.J2CUtils">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="connectionFactory" jndi-name="eis/J2CAuth" />

public class J2Ctils {
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private static String userName;
    private static String password;

    private void readAuth() throws ResourceException {
        System.out.println("Auth loaded");
            Connection conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
            Interaction interaction = (Interaction) conn.createInteraction();
            Config config = interaction.getConfig();
            userName = config.getUserName();
            password = config.getPassword();
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        if(null == userName) {
            readAuth();
        }
        return userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        if(null == password) {
            readAuth();
        }
        return password;
    }
    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Singletons or static methods don't help if you want to access a resource exactly once because every member of the cluster has it's own instance of the class.

Take in mind that neither the Java EE specification the [Spring specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300706/spring-singleton-in-clustered-environment)  do define any kind of cluster behavior. You need to search for specific vendor solution to achieve this kind of requirement. Just as an example see have a look at [@ApplicationScped in a cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062511/applicationscoped-in-a-cluster).

Other approaches to archive the expected behaviour are using a distributed lock like Zookeeper or maybe even a Queue with [duplicate message filter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/idempotent-filter).

Comment: There are 2 jvms in the cluster. I am okay if there are one instance per jvm in the cluster. But load test for 2 mins and 5 mins showed the method being called 7 and 12 times. And for 30,000 requests, I got around 100 connection timeouts with 4 jvms. So my intent is to avoid these connection timeouts. Is there a way we can ensure only once instance per jvm using Static class/method/variables?

Comment: Per default Spring Beans are Singletons, i.e. they exist only once per JVM. If you mark `getUserName()` and `getPassword()` as `synchronized` `readAuth()` will only be called once per bean except username or password are `null` or the spring context gets reloaded.